# Default value in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid/list:

```
items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridpanel',
                        reference: 'list',
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 200,
                        title: '',
                        forceFit: true,
                        bind: {
                            store: '{schedules}'
                        },
                        columns: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                dataIndex: 'revision',
                                text: 'Revision'
                            }
                        ],
```

I want to add a listener so that the record at index 0 in the store is selected by default.

I've tried playing with selModel but its not working as intended.

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: Using an afterrender listener and trying to select store.getAt(0)

Answer (score 2):

Do it on [`viewready`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-viewready) event:

```
{
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    listeners: {
        'viewready': function(g) {
            g.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        }
    },
    // ....
}
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qe6

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the store load event (as example in the controller):

```
onLaunch: function () {
    var me = this,
        grid = me.getGrid(),
        store = me.getGroupsStore();

    store.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        },
        scope: this
    });
},
```

Comment: It's just an example from my own MVC code. I get the columns from the backend and put them on my model using the metachange event of the store. When the controller is instantiated the and launched the store get loaded and reconfigures the (reuseable) grid. In that way I only need one grid for all my modules in my portal.